# Does sequential clock gating useful?

Tags: clock

I know there is clock gating method that xor-ing the input and output of FF, and use that signal as clock enable.

My quention is, I can't understand why sequential clock gating such as using STC or ODC condition is useful.

I think clock gating some serial FFs through STC condition gets the same result of gating them by xor-ing each input and output of FFs.
In case of ODC condition, i think it is effective because clk of FFs can be gated while input/output of FFs are not equal.

Does sequential clock gating through STC is really effective?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.  Currently this question seem to  looks for a detailed explanation of http://www.google.ca/patents/US8656326.